# FFMPEG. Getting nanoseconds from the beginning of captured image

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp

I have a command to split a video into images.

```
ffmpeg -i video2.mp4 -vf fps=1 frames/thumb%04d.jpg -hide_banner
```

I need to store with metadata of this image the count of nanoseconds that were from the start of the video till the moment of getting image captured.

Comment: Very unlikely. The timestamps for packets in a MP4 may have precision of up to 100 microseconds, typically less.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks for the answer. In case I can have microseconds count from the video start it would be great.

Comment: Share the console output of `ffmpeg -i video2.mp4`